# django-autocomplete-light with User - choices should be a queryset

Tags: django, django-autocomplete-light

I can't seem to make django-autocomplete-light work with the django contrib user model. Always get exception 'choices should be a queryset'

This is my autocomplete class (defined in autocomplete_ligh_registry.py):

```
import autocomplete_light
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
class UserAutocomplete(autocomplete_light.AutocompleteModelBase):
    search_fields = ['first_name']
    model = User
autocomplete_light.register(UserAutocomplete)
```

my form (in forms.py):

```
class TransactionForm(forms.Form):
    mymodel = forms.ModelChoiceField(  required=True, 
                                       queryset=User.objects.all() , 
                                   widget=autocomplete_light.ChoiceWidget('UserAutocomplete'))
```

When trying to render with {{form}}, it throws an exception: choices should be a queryset:
stack:

```
/home/prj/docs/projectos/.../src/autocomplete-light/autocomplete_light/widgets.py in render
        choices = autocomplete.choices_for_values() ...
▶ Local vars
/home/prj/docs/projectos/.../src/autocomplete-light/autocomplete_light/autocomplete/model.py in choices_for_values
        assert self.choices is not None, 'choices should be a queryset'
```

This is django 1.6 running in development. I have Users created.
django-autocomplete-light works ok with an autocompleteListBase, e.g.:

```
class OsAutocomplete(autocomplete_light.AutocompleteListBase):
    choices = ['Linux', 'BSD', 'Minix']
autocomplete_light.register(OsAutocomplete)
```

so urls.py are including the registry, urls are registered and javascript is being loaded.
Following these docs: 
http://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html#tutorial

Any pointers?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, got it... Docs don't mention but it needs choices to be explicitly defined on the autocomplete class.

```
class UserAutocomplete(autocomplete_light.AutocompleteModelBase):
    search_fields = ['email']
    choices = User.objects.all()
    model = User
autocomplete_light.register(UserAutocomplete)
```